# MonoDroid evaluation System.UnauthorizedAccessException in Directory.CreateDirectory()

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monodevelop, mvvmcross

Scenario:

Start MonoDevelop

new Android Application

Replace button click delegate with

```
string fullPath = "/data/misc.mvvmcross.customermanagement/files/_Caches/Pictures.MvvmCross/";
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath))
{
    button.Text = "exists";
}
else
{
    button.Text = "not found";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
}
```

run and click the button.
Directory.CreateDirectory will fail with

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Have tried creating a new emulator image with different API levels, but problem is still here

Any thoughts anyone?

Ok, Have created new Android Emulator image and used that.
Everything now works.

Solution:
Create a new android emulator image for the API level you want (don't forget Google API support)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this is caused by some kind of assembly/package naming issue.

I've tested this code:

```
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(FilesDir.Path, "_Caches2/Pictures.MvvmCross/2/");
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            button.Text = "exists";
        }
        else
        {
            button.Text = fullPath;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
        }
```

...and it works fine in a 2.3.3 emulator.

The data folder pattern is: `/data/ * package name * /files/`

And it is correct (I think) for one package not to be able to access the data of another.

So I'm wondering if somehow your package names are wrong - check the manifest tab and the manifest.xml file for your application?